# How to save a treeview as .csv file in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, file, csv, treeview

I need to save the current view of my QTreeView (QSortFilterProxyModel and QStandardItemModel) as a .csv file. Unfortunately, I don't know where to start...

I think I should use the QSortFilterProxyModel, because I need to save the current view, but I am not sure... Any ideas? Is there a way to get to know if a row is a parent?

**The treeview is hierarchial and has 5 columns:**

[image]

**.CSV output I need:**

```
"(0028,2110)",LossyImageCo,CS,2,00
"(00028,3000)",ModalityLUTse,SQ,,
 ,"(0028,3002)",LUTDesciptoi,US,6,4096\0\12
etc...
```

**My code so far:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < proxyModel->rowCount(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < proxyModel->columnCount(); j++)
        {
            QModelIndex index = proxyModel->index(i, j);
            qDebug() << "Data: " << proxyModel->data(index).toString();
            // How do I know when to start a child row?
        }
    }
```

**Update 1:**

I have created a file with all parent rows. How can I get the child rows?

```
QFile file(filePath);
            if (file.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
            {
                QTextStream stream(&file);              
                for (int i = 0; i < proxyModel->rowCount(); i++)
                {
                    QModelIndex index0 = proxyModel->index(i, 0);
                    QModelIndex index1 = proxyModel->index(i, 1);
                    QModelIndex index2 = proxyModel->index(i, 2);
                    QModelIndex index3 = proxyModel->index(i, 3);
                    QModelIndex index4 = proxyModel->index(i, 4);
                    stream << proxyModel->data(index0).toString() << "," <<  proxyModel->data(index1).toString() << "," << proxyModel->data(index2).toString() << "," << proxyModel->data(index3).toString() << "," << proxyModel->data(index4).toString();
                    stream << "\n";                 
                }
                file.close();
            }
```

Output:

```
(0008,0005),SpecificCharacterSet,CS,10,ISO_IR 100
(0008,0008),ImageType,CS,36,ORIGINAL\PRIMARY\M\HEADER_CORRECTED
(0008,0016),SOPClassUID,UI,26,1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4
(0008,0018),SOPInstanceUID,UI,46,1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.5.11090.5.0.5823661031981777
(0008,0020),StudyDate,DA,8,20040305
(0008,0021),SeriesDate,DA,8,20040305
(0008,0022),AcquisitionDate,DA,8,20040305
(0008,0023),ContentDate,DA,8,20040305
(0008,0030),StudyTime,TM,14,085922.859000
(0008,0031),SeriesTime,TM,14,090019.359000
(0008,0032),AcquisitionTime,TM,14,085939.762492
(0008,0033),ContentTime,TM,14,090021.062000
(0008,0050),AccessionNumber,SH,2,0
(0008,0060),Modality,CS,2,MR
(0008,0070),Manufacturer,LO,8,SIEMENS
(0008,0080),InstitutionName,LO,18,cJf7JCqV84P^te1az
(0008,0090),ReferringPhysicianName,PN,20,FLp8xklEDWOqavQWiJ9
(0008,1010),StationName,SH,8,unknown
(0008,1030),StudyDescription,LO,12,WRIST^RIGHT
(0008,103e),SeriesDescription,LO,18,SCOUT 3-PLANE RT.
(0008,1070),OperatorsName,PN,14,RIORDAN, JAMES
```

Comment: how are you populating the treeview i.e., where are you getting this data from? are you using models already?

Comment: Yep, I am using QSortFilterProxyModel and QStandardItemModel, but I need the current view (after filtering), so I am not sure if I can use them...

Comment: @ramtheconqueror Could you please take a look at my update?

Comment: I think this can be solved by recursion, but I am not sure how... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate QTreeWidget child items use QTreeWidget::topLevelItem() to access top level items and then recursively use QTreeWidgetItem::child() to iterate over lower-level children and their children.

Are you loading this dicom file yourself? You can also look at the source code for gdcmdump. Modify that code to output csv instead of its standard output. That would be straightforward.

Comment: I am not using QTreeWidget. Yes I am loading this file myself, but I need to store the current view, not a complete file. Thats the reason I am using QSortFilterProxyModel

Comment: Can't you just call topLevelItem on the first item in the view and then recurse down to the last item in the view?

Comment: I'll try later today.